# Looking for a script to convert multiline "block" comments in C/C++ to single line comments

Tags: c++, c, scripting, comments

A simple find/replace will not work for code commented out like this:

ex:

```
/* templine1
   templine2
   templine3 */
```

Got any ideas?

Comment: Any preference for scripting language?

Comment: Nasty edge case: uncommented code following the `*/` on the same line...

Comment: Preferrably linux bash script. (No this is for about 200 files that I am working with developed by a previous programmer. They didn't use any single line comments so it is impossible to comment out a section of code more than a few lines long, which is very aggravating.)

Comment: @linuxgnu123: You can use block comments to comment out blocks of code, it's usually easier than line comments actually. :o

Comment: Another edge case to consider in the solution. char *foo = "/*"; char *bar = "*/";

Comment: Or if you want to comment out a piece of code that contains block comments, use `#if 0 ... #endif`.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: I think the OPs problem is that block comments don't nest well.

Comment: Why not use a text editor that has a single-line comment feature (that allows you to comment out multiple lines at once)? That should solve the problem neatly without needing to convert all those other comments (as long as you make sure to get both delimiters of any block comment(s) in your newly-commented-out block of code, at least). Job's suggestion sounds like a good possibility as well.

Answer (score 1):

A carefully-constructed regular expression might get you where you want to go.

(OK, it's not homework ... [try here](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html) ;) )

Comment: I've edited my perl script to use that regex.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful... the following is legal:

```
if (x > /*let's think...
          I think comparing it to 3 will be a good idea! */ 3) {
     peanut();
}
```

So any script will have to make sure to put the single-line comment at the end of the line. This loses the precise location of the comment, plus you need to think what to do with things like this:

```
if (/*hmm...
      x?*/ x /* yes,
      x! */ > 3) {
    butter();
}
```

So you probably want to restrict yourself to comment blocks not appearing on the same line with other code. In that case, be aware block comments can be captured by a single regular expression, so a small [Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056518/looking-for-a-script-to-convert-multiline-block-comments-in-c-c-to-single-lin/3056623#3056623) could probably do the job.

**EDIT:** actually, "code not appearing in the same line" is not enough:

```
char* s = "hello \
           /* this is not a comment";
           /* this is */
```

**EDIT2:** If you want to cover all corner cases, I think a better solution is to [tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) the entire file. Since you can ignore many things, it wouldn't be too difficult - I've done so myself, in the past, for a C-like language. Once you get a token stream you can go over it, holding a "status" mode to keep track of strings / single-line comments / multiline comments.

Answer (score 1):

Perl hack, not tested or proved; will break some code that has `f(blah /*, bar*/)` in it

```
#open the $file and read it in
my ($fh, $file);
open $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die($!);

{ 
 local $/ = undef; 
 $file = <$fh>; 
}
close $fh;

#process it. does some assumptions about aliasing here, may not be valid.
#used the link from elsewhere for the regex
foreach my $comment ($file =~ m//\*(?:.|[\r\n])*?\*///g)
{
  my @lines = split(/\n/, $comment);
  s/^/\/\/ for @lines;
  $comment = join("\n", @lines);
}

open ">", $ARGV[0] or die($!);
print $fh $file;
close $fh;
```

Comment: This is not string-proof, and I think it's also not "\" proof (see the edit to my answer).

Comment: @Oak - added the regex from above

Answer (score 1):

If you use vim, you can use the [Nerd Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but it hasn't been properly answered.

**SOLUTION**

I have encountered this problem and come up with the following regex ('.' matches new line flag required):

```
((?<!\/)\/\*[^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))(([\r\n]\/\/[^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))*)([\r\n]+)((?!\/\/).*?\*\/)
```

this can used to repeatedly replace the beginning of each line in a comment with "//" using:

```
$1$2$4\/\/$5
```

and then a second regex:

```
\/\*(.*?)\*\/
```

can be replaced with:

```
\/\/$1
```

to remove the block start and end.

**EXPLANATION**

So, the problem is keeping the point where you insert the "//" identifiable. To do this, the comment is broken up into chunks:

```
((?<!\/)\/\*[^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))
```

$1 - Captures the first line of the comment with the opening "/*" (as long as it's not actually a single comment followed by asterisks, will match any following character except a new line, and will fail if the end of comment is encountered (negative look behind).

```
(([\r\n]\/\/[^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))*)
```

$2 - Captures any already processed lines of the comment with the opening "//" followed by the same pattern as $1. It contains $3 because it repeats as many times as necessary.

```
([\r\n]+)
```

$4 - Captures the next line after the already processed block, we know we want to put the "//" after this.

```
((?!\/\/).*?\*\/)
```

$5 - Captures the remainder of the unprocessed comment, non-greedy, up to the closing "*/"

Once all the lines have "//" added, the regex no longer matches, nor does it match single-line comments, so the seconds step completes the process (but it's so simple it doesn't need explaining).

**NOTE**

The regex still matches if there is trailing white-space after the closing "*/". This will cause it to comment out lines beyond the boundary of the block. To avoid this replace:

```
(\*\/)[\t ]+$
```

With:

```
$1
```

I have also discovered a bug with notepad++ where it mistakenly matches the entire file. In this case, you can use the following expression as an alternative to the second regex to complete conversion of only the fully processed blocks and prevent the erroneous match:

```
\/\*(([^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))(([\r\n]\/\/[^\r\n]*(?<!\*\/))*))\*\/
```

It's best to do this after there is a large reduction in the number of replacements (meaning it is processing fewer blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is a working code in DevCpp:

```
void convert_single(char source[], char dest[]){
    ifstream fin(source);
    ofstream fout(dest);
    char ch;
    while(fin.get(ch)){
        if(ch=='/')
          {
            /*strcpy(line,ch);*/
            fout<<ch;
            fin.get(ch);
            if(ch=='/')
             {
                /*strcat(line,'*');*/
                fout<<'*';
                while(fin.get(ch))
                  {
                    if(ch=='\n')
                      {
                        fout<<"*/\n";
                        break;
                        }
                    else
                       fout<<ch;
                   }
             }
            else
              fout<<ch;
            }
        else
            fout<<ch;       
    } /*end of while loop*/
    fout.close();
    fin.close();    
    return ;
}
```